# Detect Top of ListView Scroll

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to detect the Top of List view and i am using this method.

```
@Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (firstVisibleItem == 0)
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
                else
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
            }
```

This works fine, but the problem is I have attached the Header View to list as well. When I scrolled up, as soon as the first item is visible(not the Header view) it calls pull to refresh of list view. How can i detect that the List's Header is completely visible.
My List View Is

```
View imageSlider = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_slider_layout, null, false);
findViewById(imageSlider);

mPullRefreshListView.addHeaderView(imageSlider);

private void findViewById(View view) {
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    }
```

Comment: please post your List View with the header as well. It would be more easy to reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: @Anthea Ihave Added the code. Please have a look.

Comment: read my answer below, it tell u when when header is visible completely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hmm, Interesting answer lies in onTouch listener rather then onScroll, see the implementation below, it exactly tells u when header is completely visible, you can refine the logic further.. its just a quick implementation form me.

```
    // Set a on touch listener for your list
    mList.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           // get the top of  first child
            View mView = mList.getChildAt(0);
            int top = mView.getTop();


            switch(event.getAction()){

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // see if it top is at Zero, and first visible position is at 0
                if(top == 0 && mList.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Header Item Visible", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            // dont forget to retrun false here
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply identifies it with visibleitemCount in onScroll Listener also.

Firstly identify your listview's visible item count at the top of listview include the header. you can get the count by toasting or debugg the code.

in my case
     my listview's normal visibleItemCount is 3 and at the place of top it is 2 (with headerview), then my code is work for me.

```
 @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, 
                                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if(firstVisibleItem==0&&visibleItemCount==2)
            {
                swp.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else{
                swp.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }
```